# php artisan config:cache producing an e (laravel)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am ruuning the below command at laravel:

```
root@vmi194229:/var/www/html# php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
e
Configuration cached successfully!
root@vmi194229:/var/www/html#
```

However the config cache got cleared, but produced an "e" in the terminal. Why the e is coming !?

Comment: it is somewhere in your code. check route files, service providers etc.

Comment: check your code, by mistakenly you have typed letter `e`